# Strange V in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have maybe strange, but very simple question... What this strange V means in InteliJ, and how can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: It looks more like a checkmark try clicking it

Comment: It is unclickable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bookmark. You probably pressed F11 while having that class selected.